# Change cookie of domain B from domain A , they are on the same dedicated server

Tags: cookies, dns

I have a dedicated server, which hosts 2 domains, let's say A and B.
I know about the cross-origin policy, that is impossible to read the cookies from another domain, but is it somehow possible to do it when they have the same hardware/owner/server/file system, etc?

I have realized an interesting thing, I have ads on domain A, and there are a lot of cookies from ad networks. How they did do it? Can I do something similar with my two domains?

Thanks for the answers/suggestions, I have really no experience in this sphere.

Answer (score 0):

when you run advertisements on your domain, you include some JavaScript code provided by these ad networks.

When the script is executed, the script can create and read cookies associated with domain from where the script came from.